# Hide system tray icons - Terminal Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

We just got a new backup device that installed a client on our Server 2003 Enterprise TS servers. I would like to hide this system tray icon from all users so they don't tinker around with it. The program itself doesn't have a setting to hide the system tray icon.

Is there a way to hide this system tray icon for all users? Is there a group policy or registry setting I can use?

Comment: You may want to specify which device/application this is to get better answers for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the backup client itself runs as a service, you may want to check and see if an extra quick-launch type program is set to run for all users. A couple places to check include:

- All Users' Start Menu -> Programs -> Startup
- HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run

Comment: Awesome insight! I found the sys tray application in the All Users -> Programs -> Startup folder and deleted it. Thnx!